# HANA Studio Job schedule for Calculation Views

Tags: hana

Using HANA STUDIO, I have created two calculation views, 'Cal_V1', and 'Cal_V2'.
'Cal_V1' creates a out put 'view T1'. This output view is input to Calculation view 'Cal_V2'. Calculation view 'Cal_V2' processes data on 'view T1' and finally outputs 'view T2'.

I can run these calculation views manually, one after another. But the problem is I have to schedule these views to run automatically one after another. I searched internet. I found the XS Engine can schedule Hana procedures.

But how to schedule Calculation Views ?

Answer (score 0):

Calculation views are executed ad-hoc, whenever you need the result.

Result sets of any calculation view are not stored somewhere, so scheduling the execution does not make any sense.

That also applies to your stacked/dependent calculation views: when you query your `CAL_V2` it implicitly will execute the necessary parts of `CAL_V1` just at that point in time.

If you are manually storing the result sets in tables (which is usually not a good idea) you might as well just instrument the order of execution via an SQLScript procedure where you require `SEQUENTIAL EXECUTION`. That procedure then can be scheduled with the XSEngine scheduler.

Coming back to the original question: calculation views cannot be scheduled.